# BroadcastReceiver passing value error

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I want to pass `integer` value from an `Activity` Class(`PlayListActivity.java`) to my `Service`(`AudioService.java`) Class. But when I click on the `ListItem`, my application gets stopped. I couldn`t figure the error. Hope someone could help me

error in logCat:

```
  java.lang.RunTimeException: error recieveing broadcast Intent {act-com.exaple.serviceaudio.AudioService.PLAY_SONG flg=0x10 (has extras)} in com.example.serviceaudio.AudioService$AudioPlayerBroadcastReciever@41b4e818.........
```

Here are my codes.

PlayLlistActivity.java

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        playSongSong(position);         
            }});

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    unbindService(serviceConnection);
    super.onDestroy();

}

public void playSongSong(int songIndex){
    Intent intent = new Intent(AudioService.PLAY_SONG);
    intent.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
    this.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

AudioService.java

```
public static final String PLAY_SONG_BASE = "com.example.serviceaudio.AudioService";
public static final String PLAY_SONG = PLAY_SONG_BASE + ".PLAY_SONG";
private AudioPlayerBroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new AudioPlayerBroadcastReceiver();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.v("AudioService", "AudioPlayer: onCreate() called");
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(PLAY_SONG);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);            
}

public void onDestroy() {

    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}

private class AudioPlayerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
       int currentSongIndex = intent.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");


        if(PLAY_SONG.equals(action)) {
            Log.d("AudioService", "Action not recognized: " + action);
            playSong(currentSongIndex); 
}}
```

when I comment the `int currentSongIndex = intent.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");` and `playSong(currentSongIndex); there is no error but doing nothing.

Comment: Have you set `AudioService.PLAY_SONG` in `action` tag in `intent-filter` which you are calling right  now?

Comment: @dreamcoder, what do you mean. in `androidManifest`?

Comment: If you are using custom `Action` then you have to define this in `receiver`

Comment: @dreamcoder, I did like this `    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(PLAY_SONG);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter); `

Answer (score 0):

A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active.

This has important repercussions to what you can do in an onReceive(Context, Intent) implementation: anything that requires asynchronous operation is not available, because you will need to return from the function to handle the asynchronous operation, but at that point the BroadcastReceiver is no longer active and thus the system is free to kill its process before the asynchronous operation completes.

In short the life of broadcast receiver is very short and shot not do any long running task in it. At max try to raise an intent and do the work there.

This is causing crash for you and when you comment that it works fine for you.

Comment: You can write a static method in which you can do the work what you are doing in onReceive() now and call it from onReceive(). Normally such functions are written as static menthods in Util class whihc you can call from any where. Or you can write a handler to do the work and call the handler from onReceive().

Answer (score 0):

As you are facing problem there is a best way to use the data of the activity i.e store the value through shared prefernce from activity like this:

```
 String share_pref_file = "song_index_file";      
 SharedPreferences prefs1 = getSharedPreferences(
            share_pref_time_file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = prefs1.edit();
 editor1.putString("songIndex", formattedDate);
 editor1.commit();
```

And fetch it from service like this:

```
 String share_pref_file = "song_index_file";
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(share_pref_file,
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 String strJson = prefs.getString("songIndex", "");
```

This technique might help you.